# Natural deduction proof without assumption

Tags: propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

$$(((p\iff q)\iff r)\wedge(q\iff r))\implies p$$

Should be done with natural deduction, but up to $60$ steps.
If I assume $\neg\:p$ probably I may finish up to $20$ steps, but without assumption I didn't find good way.
If start could be separated by deduction rules and in the end also collect by same rules.

$$
\begin{aligned}
&1.& &\neg\: ((((p\iff q)\iff r)\land (q\iff r))\implies p)&\hspace{20ex} & \\
&2.& &(((p\iff q)\iff r) \land  (q\iff r))& & \\
&3.& &\neg\:  p& -&\text{ assume } \\
&4.& &(p\iff q\iff r) \land  (q\iff r)&  -&\text{ from }  4  \\
&5.& &(p\iff q\iff r)  \land E,4 & & \\
&6.& &(q\iff r) \land E,4 & & \\
&7.& &p\implies (q\iff r) &  -&\text{ from }  4 \\
&8.& &(q\iff r) \implies p & -&\text{ from }  4 \\
&9.& &p(\implies E 6,8) & & 
\end{aligned}
$$

where $\land$ is negation

Comment: Do you need to use less than 60 steps? If you found a proof where you assume $\neg p$ then reach a contradiction, then why cant you use that? What exactly is it that you want help with? Please show is how you start this and where you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just started in this way, but I am not sure if I've used appropriate rules of deduction and axioms.                                (((p⟺q)⟺r)  &  (q⟺r))⇒p

Comment: Well, since you have not shown anything you have done so far, it is impossible to know if you have used the rules correctly or not.

Comment: 1. ~ ((((p⟺q)⟺r)  &  (q⟺r))⇒p )                                                          2.    (((p⟺q)⟺r)  &  (q⟺r))                                                                3. ~ p - assume                                                                                     4. (p⟺q⟺r)  &  (q⟺r)      from 2                                                          5. (p⟺q⟺r)     &E,4                                                                            6. (q⟺r)     &E,4                                                                    7.p=>(q<=>r) from 4

Comment: Please edit you post with these extra steps, show as much as you can, and write it in Latex, so it will be readable.

Comment: 8.(q<=>r) => p from 4                                                                                9. p (=>6,8)

Comment: 8.(q<=>r) => p from 4                                                                               9.p(=>E 6,8)                                                                                            I am not sure if I have to use 3 and 9 with some rules (&I or some another) to show that final conclusion is F. Is it possible to use rules from start without assumption to decomposed everything and after that again  make composition using rules to get start formula. Also I am not familiar with Latex.

Comment: @Phyllotactic: Hello, I noticed that you've suggested a lot of tag edits in the past few hours. Please note: (1) Editing sprees flood the front page with old questions, so it is highly encouraged that you only edit a few questions at a time. (2) If you are going to bump old questions, try to make the question as good as you can. That means TeX-ifying math, correcting grammar, making titles more specific, etc. (3) Please take into account question quality and consider whether it's actually worth bumping such questions, particularly on closed or negative-score questions.

Comment: @epimorphic Thank you I did not realise that tag edits also bumped question, I avoided touching the content of these posts specifically to not flood the front page with old post, very sorry for that.